# Access denied for user 'user' error while trying to connect to online DB

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I saw couple of other posts here with the same title, and tried to follow their solutions but no help..

I am trying to connect unity3d 5 to a online database. but I keep getting this error

> MySqlException: Access denied for user 'altjenb'@'217.73.137.52'
>   (using password: YES) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket ()
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateNew ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection ()
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver ()
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

this is my source code in C#:

```
MySqlConnection connectionstring = new MySqlConnection("Server=mysql8.db4free.net; Port=3306;Database=testdb;UserId= altjenb; Password = faeefg; ");

string cmdText = "SELECT 1 FROM Login WHERE Username = awd";
using (MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connectionstring)) {
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    connectionstring.Open();
    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("spunon");
    }
    else {
        Debug.LogWarning("punon");
    }
    }
```

why do I keep getting this? I dont understand..

EDIT: after getting a tweet from the db4free, they suggested to change the port from 3306 to 3307. but still getting an error.

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharacterSet].get_Item
>   (System.String key) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)

Comment: What if you remove the spaces from the connection string?

Comment: still the same. edited the post again. give a look at it please

Comment: I'm guessing your credentials are wrong. They don't work for me. P.S. You really shouldn't be posting them here.

Comment: who said those are the real ones?

Comment: Good point. In any case, you're asking a completely different question now. You should probably close this and post it separately.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not understanding you.. the error is still the same.why should I create 2 posts for the same error?

Comment: How is KeyNotFoundException the same as Access denied?

Comment: KeyNotFound exception error was shown after the admins of db4free suggested to try to change the port to 3307 and see if it works. but the main port of the page is 3306 and I am still going with it. added that here so can give someone more information for the error I am facing

Comment: If they said to use 3307, you should probably use 3307.

Comment: they suggested if its possible try to change port to 3307 and see if it works. they didnt said do it, but try if it changes things.. and the port does

Comment: Well apparently it does work.

Comment: okay, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change from mysql8.db4free.net to db4free.net and the port 3306. same user details. it should work